# How to use Chrome Options in Ruby Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The below snippet is from official page [Ruby Bindings](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings); however, it fails to work

```
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
  options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
  options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

**Error:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have autoloading disabled? All of the different browsers (including their options) are autoloaded in. Chrome for example: `autoload :Chrome,    'selenium/webdriver/chrome'`

Comment: am not sure; but why autoload? options doesnt work if autoload is disabled?

Comment: Yes, autoload should register the fact that `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options` exists but will only load it when you use it. If autoload is broken somehow then this won't work

Comment: so, how to enable it?

Comment: ah! you mean auto-complete in ruby? I dont think its an issue, cos i get error during execution through terminal. you can find the output in question

Comment: I'm not sure if autoload can be disabled but it might not be working properly for some reason. If no one else comes along to provide an answer, you could always `gem unpack` into your directory and edit the `autoload` line to be `require` instead

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**For `Selenium 4` & `Chrome <75` users**

```
  options = {
      args: ['disable-infobars', 'disable-gpu', 'privileged', 'ignore-certificate-errors', 'no-default-browser-check'],
      w3c: true,
      mobileEmulation: {},
      prefs: {
          :protocol_handler => {
              :excluded_schemes => {
                  tel: false,
              }
          }
      },
      extensions: [ Base64.strict_encode64(File.open("../your_extension.crx", 'rb').read) ]
  }

  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(options: options)
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: caps)
```

---

**For `Selenium 3` users**

Used switches to define chrome options

```
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("desiredCapabilities" => {"takesScreenshot" => true}, "chromeOptions" => {"binary" => "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"})
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps, switches: %w[--incognito --screen-size=1200x800]
```

Or

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, switches: %w[--incognito]
```

**RemoteWebDriver**

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "disable-infobars" ]})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: caps
```

> Chrome switches list
>
> https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: FYI, in recent versions of selenium: `WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :args or :switches is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options#add_argument instead.` Another way is `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: [<args>])`.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
args = ['ignore-certificate-errors', 'disable-popup-blocking', 'disable-translate']

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: args)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
```

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me. I can run Selenium on a Mac in Ruby without having to keep logging into the website I'm testing!

```
    dir = "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome"
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ["user-data-dir=#{dir}"])
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, capabilities: options)
```

Got this code from the

[Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options API Reference](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium%2FWebDriver%2FChrome%2FOptions:initialize)